# I need to know if is there a way to exec something everytime i define a class

Tags: ruby

Like i said in the title. I need to know if is there some way to execute something everytime i define a class

Like puts "fifi".

When i do this:

```
class Pipipupu
end

=> fifi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Object
  def self.inherited(obj)
    puts "fifi" if obj == Pipipupu
  end
end

class Pipipupu
end
```

diplays `"fifi"`.

```
class Cat
end
```

displays nothing. See [Class#inherited](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Class.html#method-i-inherited), which is referred to as a *callback* or *hook* method.

If you wish to display `"fifi"` whenever any class is created replace

```
puts "fifi" if obj == Pipipupu
```

with

```
puts "fifi" if obj.is_a? Class
```

Comment: Hey man! Your answer actually really helped me out!, But i have an issue with it. Redefining self.inherited(obj) is turning my pry crazy. So how can i make self.inherited(obj) mantain what it was doing before, but also add this logic?

Comment: @Nicolas, I don't know why it would cause a problem with Pry. IRB has no such problem and it runs fine from the command line. Getting it to work with Pry is a different question. Try this: add the line `super` at the end of the `inherited` method. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Still breaking my pry, don't know why. Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Note that you may need to restart Pry to properly test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `inherited` hook to `BasicObject`:

```
class BasicObject
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    puts "fifi"
  end
end
```

To prevent it from screwing up other hooks, instead of redefining it you can prepend a module that prints and calls super to invoke the already registered behavior:

```
module Hook
  def inherited(subclass)
    puts "fifi"
    super
  end
end

BasicObject.singleton_class.prepend(Hook)
```

Then:

```
irb> class Foo; end
fifi
=> nil
```

Alternatively, add the hook to `Object`. For `Foo` above the implicit superclass is `Object`. But `BasicObject` is the superclass of `Object`. Adding the hook to `BasicObject` will also print for classes that specify `BasicObject` as superclass.